# How to automatic store value in database when checkbox is checked in web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How to automatic store value in database when checkbox is checked and refresh my To do list. Here is my code:

This is my HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpTodos" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("TodosID", "{0:d}") %></td>             
                <td><%# Eval("TaskName", "{0:d}") %></td>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cbisdone" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" checked='<%#Eval("IsDone")%>'></asp:CheckBox></td>                                                                                                       
               <td><%# Eval("TaskDate", "{0:d}") %></td>                                        
            </tr>                                            
    </ItemTemplate>                                        
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is code behind:

```
var todos2 = ctx.Todos.ToList().Where(t=> t.IsDone == false).ToList();
rpTodos.DataSource = todos2;
rpTodos.DataBind();
```

Comment: You need a "checked" event on the server if you enable the autopostback on the checkbox. It's called "OnCheckedChanged" https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `OnCheckedChanged` event in your aspx page.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbisdone" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" checked='<%#Eval("IsDone")%>' OnCheckedChanged="cbisdone_changed"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Create a new event that would listen to raised event and cast the sender object back to Checkbox.

```
protected void cbisdone_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
              // Update the status in DB.
        }
    }
}
```